# Get value of Last slash and before . in php

Tags: php

I have array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR04A-94527.jpg
    [1] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR05A-95528.jpg
    [2] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR06A-961000001.jpg
    [3] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR06A-96529.jpg
    [4] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR07A-971000002.jpg
    [5] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR07A-97530.jpg
    [6] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR08A-981000003.jpg
    [7] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR08A-98531.jpg
    [8] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR09A-991000004.jpg
    [9] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR09A-99532.jpg
    [10] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR09A-99533.jpg
    [11] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR09A-99534.jpg
    [12] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/Syno53.jpg
    [13] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/Syno54.jpg
    [14] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/Syno55.jpg
    [15] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/Syno56.jpg
    [16] => C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/Syno57.jpg
)
```

I want to get value after last slash and before .jpg like SyR04A-94527,SyR05A-95528 etc..

Comment: `$string = explode('/','C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR04A-94527.jpg');`
`$lastVal = end($string);`
`$getName = explode('.', $lastVal); `
`echo $result = $getName[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse filenames, and PHP already has plenty of built-in functions to do that. There's no need to manipulate the string itself with `explode` or regular expressions, etc:

```
$filename = 'C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR04A-94527.jpg';

echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
// SyR04A-94527
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regx:

```
<?php
$a = [
    'C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR04A-94527.jpg',
    'C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR05A-95528.jpg'
];

foreach( $a AS $path ){
    if( preg_match('/\/([^\/]+)\.[a-z]+$/i', $path, $match))
        print_r($match[1]."\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
 SyR04A-94527
 SyR05A-95528
```

You can test it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/081543329dda8b9e0ef59836995184171ff4ce66

I was going to use `pathinfo` but my sandbox site has it disabled, and I'm to lazy to turn my server on.  But it would be something like this:

```
$a = [
   'C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR04A-94527.jpg',
   'C:\wamp\www\sthub\application\controllers/../../download/qr/SyR05A-95528.jpg'
];

foreach( $a AS $path )
    echo pathinfo ($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME)."\n";
```

Cheers!